# AxiosError: Network Error\n and CORS Issue on React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, http, axios

I'm calling API from https://api.wisecapitals.com/cronjobs/fetchXERate. But I'm getting error on the console of the dev tools:

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.wisecapitals.com/cronjobs/fetchXERate' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Dashboard.tsx:79  Error fetching data: AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_NETWORK"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Network Error"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}stack: "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80957:14)"[[Prototype]]: Error
fetchData @ Dashboard.tsx:79
await in fetchData (async)
(anonymous) @ Dashboard.tsx:84
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26935
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201
scheduleRefresh @ react-dom.development.js:27795
(anonymous) @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:304
performReactRefresh @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:293
(anonymous) @ RefreshUtils.js:100
setTimeout (async)
enqueueUpdate @ RefreshUtils.js:98
executeRuntime @ RefreshUtils.js:259
$ReactRefreshModuleRuntime$ @ Dashboard.tsx:58
./src/components/Dashboard.tsx @ Dashboard.tsx:58
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
_requireSelf @ hot module replacement:102
apply @ jsonp chunk loading:407
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:344
internalApply @ hot module replacement:342
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:279
waitForBlockingPromises @ hot module replacement:233
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:277
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:276
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:256
Promise.then (async)
hotCheck @ hot module replacement:247
check @ dev-server.js:14
(anonymous) @ dev-server.js:69
emit @ events.js:153
reloadApp @ reloadApp.js:38
warnings @ index.js:274
(anonymous) @ socket.js:62
client.onmessage @ WebSocketClient.js:45
xhr.js:256 
        
        
        POST https://api.wisecapitals.com/cronjobs/fetchXERate net::ERR_FAILED
```

This is the code I'm calling API:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
import { TableFooter, CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const label = { inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'Switch demo' } };
const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 15,
  },
}));

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
  },
  // hide last border
  "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
    border: 0,
  },
}));

const SearchBarContainer = styled("div")({
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "flex-end", // Align to the right
  marginBottom: "10px",
  paddingRight: "10px", // Add some right padding
});

const SearchInput = styled("input")({
  width: "300px", // Set a fixed width for the input
  padding: "10px",
  borderRadius: "5px",
  border: "2px solid #6d2828",
});

const LoadingSpinner = styled(CircularProgress)`
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
`;

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [xeRate, setXeRate] = useState(null); // Initialize state variable

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch data from the API
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://api.wisecapitals.com/cronjobs/fetchXERate', {
          from: 'USD',
          to: 'LKR'
        }, {
          auth: {
            username: 'ronak',
            password: 'password123test'
          }
        });
        // Update the state with the received data
        if (response.data && response.data.forward && response.data.forward.LKR) {
          setXeRate(response.data.forward.LKR);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    // Call the function
    fetchData();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this useEffect runs once when component mounts

  return (
    <>
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Currencies Dashboard</h1>
      <div
        style={{
          margin: "2px",
          padding: "10px",
          height: "500px",
          overflow: "auto",
          position: "relative", // Add relative positioning
        }}
      >
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
            <TableHead style={{ position: "sticky" }}>
              <StyledTableRow>
                <StyledTableCell>Currencies </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell>XE Rate</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell>Our Rate</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell>Turn on Ratio</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell>Our Ratio</StyledTableCell>
              </StyledTableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              <StyledTableRow>
                <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  USD
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell>{xeRate || 'Loading...'}</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell>332</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell><Switch {...label} defaultChecked /></StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell>98%</StyledTableCell>
              </StyledTableRow>
            </TableBody>
            <TableFooter>
              <TableRow></TableRow>
            </TableFooter>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <div style={{ position: "absolute", right: "10px", marginTop: "10px"}}>
          <Button variant="contained">Update</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, I don't have access to the backend. So, I can't enable CORS to backend. I can't understand how this CORS error happen to the react frontend and the how it related to AxiosError. Same request work well in postman. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CORS proxy to use in the front end by:

- Cloning this repo https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere
- Don't make any changes to the code and deploy the cloned repo to a cloud application platform (I use https://www.heroku.com/)
- This will give you a URL to your proxy (eg https://my-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com)
- Then you append your proxy URL to the beginning of the URL you are making the API request to, for example:

  axios.get('https://my-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://api.wisecapitals.com/cronjobs/fetchXERate')